# Consuming a WSDL/Web service in C#/VisualStudio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, powershell, wsdl

While there are many other topics that provide great information on the topic posted here already, I've not yet been able to find the answer to my dilemma.

While I'm somewhat competent with PowerShell, I am completely new with C#/VisualStudio. I have some PowerShell code that consumes a Web service that works perfectly well:

```
function Modify-SPMLObject() {
  param(
    [string]$Uri
    , [string]$ObjectDN
    , [PSCredential]$Creds
    , [hashtable]$Attributes
  )

  $MyService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $Uri -Credential $Creds
  $Type = $MyService.GetType().Namespace
  $ModifyRequest = New-Object -TypeName ($Type + ".CModifyRequest")

  $CPSOID = New-Object -TypeName ($Type + ".CPSOID")
  $CPSOID.ID = $ObjectDN
  $ModifyRequest.psoID = $CPSOID

  $Modifications = @()
  foreach ($Attribute in $Attributes.Keys) {
    $Modification = New-Object -TypeName ($Type + ".modification")
    $Modification.Name = $Attribute
    $Modification.Value = $Attributes.$Attribute
    $Modification.Operation = "replace"
    $Modifications += $Modification
  }
  $ModifyRequest.modification = $Modifications
  $MyService.modify($ModifyRequest)
}
```

My challenge is converting this to C# in VisualStudio. In lieu of the call to *New-WebServiceProxy*, I've included a reference in my project to the Web service. The reference is named *MyService*. Hence, the code I've created thus far:

```
var ModifyRequest = new MyService.CModifyRequest();
var CPSOID = new MyService.CPSOID();
CPSOID.ID = "a hard-coded value for now";
ModifyRequest.psoID = CPSOID;

var modifications = new MyService.modification[1];
var modification = new MyService.modification();
modification.name = "another hard-coded value for the moment";
modification.operation = "replace";
modification.value = new string[1] { "This is a test" };
modifications[0] = modification;
ModifyRequest.modification = modifications;
```

The one thing that I haven't been able to figure out, however, is how, in C#, to accomplish the task that the PowerShell version accomplishes thus:

```
$MyService.modify($ModifyRequest)
```

In VS, if I try to call:

```
MyService.modify(ModifyRequest);
```

I get the message

> Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'modify' does not exist in the namespace 'WebApplication2.MyService' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any tips are most appreciated!

EDIT: Found the solution. In answer to LachlanB, typing "MyService" provided a list of methods and classes - but **not** the *modify* operation that I was seeking and defined in the WSDL thus:

```
<wsdl:operation name="modify">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Changes the specified object on the target.</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:input message="tns:modifySoapIn"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:modifySoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

What I needed to include was, first, the reference:

```
using WebApplication2.MyService;
```

With that, I could then call:

```
MyApplicationClassName webService = new MyApplicationClassName();
CModifyResponse response = webService.modify(ModifyRequest);
```

where "MyApplicationClassName" was automatically generated as was listed in References.cs in the following statement:

```
public partial class MyApplicationClassName : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
```

Thanks to those that tried to help!

Comment: Why don't you use Service Reference ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: I *am* using a service reference - or at least I thought I was. "MyService" in the C# code is the name as defined by the reference.

Comment: Are you trying to call a web service that has a method named "modify"? What happens when you type "MyService" and then a dot? Does it show any other functions you can call?

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct. Typing "MyService<dot>" brings up a list of classes and methods - but *not* the "modify" operation. Actually, just managed to answer my own question - will post the full answer momentarily.